# Use JAXB to create Object from XML String with Multiple Groups in XML file

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, soap

I need to convert XML string into java object.

This is the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA_DS>
<G_1>
<TERM_ID>4</TERM_ID><NAME>30 Net</NAME>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

I have created Class like this;

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DATA_DS")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymentTerm {

    @XmlElement(name = "TERM_ID")
    private double termId;

    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    private String termName;



    public double getTermId() {
        return termId;
    }
    public void setTermId(double termId) {
        this.termId = termId;
    }
    public String getTermName() {
        return termName;
    }
    public void setTermName(String termName) {
        this.termName = termName;
    }



}
```

In Main Class

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PaymentTerm.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
PaymentTerm paymentTerm = (PaymentTerm) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

This doesn't unmarshell the XML string properly because of nested groups in XML file.

If I remove the G_1 group from XML file then it convert perfectly. I need to do conversion with G_1 group

Where I have to fix the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<DATA_DS>` contains one element, `<G_1>`, which itself contains two elements, `<TERM_ID>` and `<NAME>`, so your objects needs to reflect that, i.e. the class representing `<DATA_DS>` must have one field, typed to be a class representing `<G_1>`, which must have two fields.

> Where I have to fix the code?

You need to create a class for `<G_1>`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DATA_DS")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymentTerm {

    @XmlElement(name = "G_1", required = true)
    private PaymentGroup group;

}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymentGroup {

    @XmlElement(name = "TERM_ID", required = true)
    private double termId;

    @XmlElement(name = "NAME", required = true)
    private String termName;

}
```

You should also consider why `<G_1>` exists, e.g. can there be more than one `<G_1>` inside `<DATA_DS>`? If so, make it a list:

```
@XmlElement(name = "G_1", required = true)
private List<PaymentGroup> groups;
```